# Is there a unique user-agent value for a Powershell request?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, web, request, user-agent

I'm trying to parse out requests coming in to a web page from Powershell vs Browser.

From the user-agent string I can't seem to find a fully unique user-agent specific to Powershell.

Or is there another value/header to look at to separate them?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`Invoke-WebRequest` documentation on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6), the following is said about the default `UserAgent` parameter value:

> The default user agent is similar to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.15063; en-US) PowerShell/6.0.0` with slight variations for each operating system and platform.

This can be altered though very easily using either a direct string or taking a predefined value from the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.psuseragent_members(v=vs.85).aspx) class